# MongoDB and NodeJS cannot create collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

So I used this exact code about 8 months ago and it worked fine, now suddenly this way of setup does not seem to work. I cannot manage to find what is wrong here and it seems the database just is not connecting at all. Is there a better way to go about this?

```js
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = 'mongodb://toor:root@mongodbdatabase:27017/'

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

let con;
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    con = db.db("mongodbdatabase");
})

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('/createDatabase', (req, res) => {
    con.createCollection("HiveDB", function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Collection Created")
    })
    res.send();
})

console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Here is the error that I am getting when navigating to localhost:83/createDatabase

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createCollection')
    at /usr/src/app/server.js:28:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at SendStream.error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (node:events:537:28)
```

Im running with docker compose as well

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install express --save
RUN npm install mongodb --save
RUN npm install -g loadtest --save

COPY server.js /usr/src/app/server.js
COPY /public /usr/src/app/public


CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:

  mainserver:
    build: ./main
    depends_on:
      - mongodbdatabase
    container_name: mainServer
    ports:
      - "83:8080"


  mongodbdatabase:
    image: mongo
    container_name: monDataBase
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: toor
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: your database url needs to be 'mongodb://toor:root@mongodbdatabase:27017/{Your_databse}'

Comment: @RohitMahto I still get the same error. Seeing from my containers, what woud the name of my database be?

Comment: Hi please read this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: You can provide database in the mongo url or you can omit it providing you specify database in the code. The problem here is different.

Answer (score 0):

I will direct you to the relevant documentation from the mongodb client github readme [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb)

In the code snippet you have pasted, you set the `con` variable with the `MongoClient` connection but what if the connection fails (and `err` is provided) ? So the assignment to `con` probably failed and thats the reason it is `undefined` in the context of the router.

I would recommend to copy & paste the example from the link i provided.

Using the async/await syntax you can provide the mongodb client to the route handler.

And here is a code snippet using your example:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = 'mongodb://toor:root@mongodbdatabase:27017/'

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

async function init() {
   try{
     const client = await new MongoClient(url).connect()
   }catch(err) {
     console.error(err.message)
   }
   const db = client.db("HiveDB")
   app.use('/', express.static('public'));

   app.get('/createDatabase', (req, res) => {
     db.createCollection("HiveDB", function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Collection Created")
     })
     res.send();
   })

   

   app.listen(PORT, HOST,()=>{
   console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
   });
}
init()
```